# Quicksort algorithm is nearly working but somehow elements near the center of the array are slightly unsorted

Tags: java

I'm working on a recursive implementation of Quicksort, but I can't seem to get it correct. There is always some part of the array that somehow is out of order. Sometimes I sorts perfectly for smaller arrays but always when I test it on array size 100, the first few and last few indexes are sorted correctly, but the middle few aren't.

Here is my Quicksort class

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Quicksort recursive implementation
 */
public class Quicksort {

    private int[] arr;

    public Quicksort(int size) {
        arr = new int[size];
        autoFillArr(size);
    }

    public void autoFillArr(int size) {
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < size) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randInt = random.nextInt(200) - 100;
            arr[counter] = randInt;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public void quickSort() {
        quickSort(0, arr.length-1);
    }

    public void quickSort(int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
        if (leftIndex >= rightIndex) {
            return;
        }
        int pivot = (leftIndex + rightIndex)/2;
        int lEnd = partition(leftIndex, rightIndex, pivot);
        quickSort(leftIndex, lEnd-1);
        quickSort(lEnd, rightIndex);
    }

    /**
     * @return  The position of the left point.
     */
    public int partition(int leftIndex, int rightIndex, int pivot) {
        while (leftIndex <= rightIndex) {
            while (arr[leftIndex] < arr[pivot]) {
                leftIndex++;
            }
            while (arr[rightIndex] > arr[pivot]) {
                rightIndex--;
            }
            if (leftIndex <= rightIndex) {
                swap(leftIndex, rightIndex);
                leftIndex++;
                rightIndex--;
            }
        }
        return leftIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the element at position leftIndex with the element at position
     * rightIndex.
     */
    public void swap(int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
        int temp = arr[leftIndex];
        arr[leftIndex] = arr[rightIndex];
        arr[rightIndex] = temp;
    }

    public int[] getArr() {
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: My first instinct would be to look for an off-by-one error.

Comment: You've omitted the final `swap()` of the pivot element. Check your source material.

Comment: The other thing is that `partition` presumably will fail to work properly in some cases, because if say `arr[leftIndex] >= arr[pivot]` (i.e. the values) then leftIndex will keep moving up past the end of the array.  Same for then next while.  A good test case would catch this ... I'm thinking for a test case make an array where the mid-point value larger than all the other values - partition will walk off the end of the array.  Additionally try size 2 elements (2 have partition point=0 and the value can never be less than itself so leftIndex moves up... then if next value is smaller it barfs.

Comment: Actually ignore this - the have good test cases is correct .. but I'd missed the obvious leftIndex <= pivot <= rightIndex ... At the point where leftIndex == pivot then the while will terminate ... so the only scenario you need to be sure of is that rightIndex MUST be >= pivot and leftIndex MUST be <= pivot .. it looks to be guaranteed by quickSort(left,right) because of the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `partition()` method has a couple of problems. You need to pick a pivot value rather than an index. In your `partition()` method is possible for your left or right index to move past the pivot index and therefore swap the pivot value. I'm not sure how you fix that. If you run out of indexes on one side of the pivot you still need to make sure every thing on the other side is on the correct side of the pivot.
I've included a simpler solution that uses the last value in the set as the pivot value and then moves it to the correct location before returning the index.

```
public class Quicksort {

private int[] arr;

public Quicksort(int size) {
    arr = new int[size];
    autoFillArr(size);
}

public void autoFillArr(int size) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < size) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randInt = random.nextInt(200) - 100;
        arr[counter] = randInt;
        counter++;
    }
}

public void quickSort() {
    quickSort(0, arr.length-1);
}

public void quickSort(int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
    if (leftIndex >= rightIndex) {
        return;
    }
    
    int pivot = partition(leftIndex, rightIndex);
    quickSort(leftIndex, pivot-1);
    quickSort(pivot+1, rightIndex);
}

/**
 * @return  The position of the left point.
 */
public int partition(int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
    
    int pivot = arr[rightIndex];
    
    int i = leftIndex -1;
    for (int j = leftIndex; j <= rightIndex - 1; j++) {
        if (arr[j] < pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(i+1, rightIndex);
    return i+1;
}

/**
 * Swaps the element at position leftIndex with the element at position
 * rightIndex.
 */
public void swap(int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
    int temp = arr[leftIndex];
    arr[leftIndex] = arr[rightIndex];
    arr[rightIndex] = temp;
}

public int[] getArr() {
    return arr;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks so much. Using the pivot instead of pivot index fixed it like a charm.